# How can i get response of a request and use it as parameter for another GET request ? (in okhttp)

Tags: java, json, okhttp

I get a request from

> http://localhost:8080/hello-world/login?name=ilkin&password=pass

Response:

```
{"token":"b49cd24c-d35f-4c5c-aac5-9017b8d3641d"}
```

Now I need to use this token value and create another get request with it.

> http://localhost:8080/hello-world/person?token=token

How can I do all of that with okhttp?

Comment: Make the first request, get the token, use it for making the second request.

Comment: Yea i know that but i have no idea how am i going to create a GET request first in okhttp an get that token from it.

Comment: Can you please post the code of your login request?

Comment: if you request from jsp you can use ajax for it

Comment: Do you really need that code ? I just want to write a okhttp code to test it. Why do you need login request code.  I can't change anything on the code. I only want to test requests.

Comment: do you know how can i create a get request using okhttps ? Atleast

Comment: if you want just test so you use postman

Comment: I need to learn about okhttps and writing testing codes for requests .